# Certainly not off-topic

Tags: discussion

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9121/software-for-assisting-in-handling-large-data

This question is not off-topic as it's about a specific specialised type of software. Software rec's is general 'how do i edit my video' type questions. Data scientists here would use software that answers my question daily. Stating questions involving software that is used by data scientists daily is off-topic is grossly incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

> Software rec's is general 'how do i edit my video' type questions

I would like to point out to you that the software recs site is not just for simple software suggestions. Your question as framed, would be perfectly on-topic in Software Recommendations.

Questions about what a Machine Learning/Data Science software (or) technique can do, are on-topic in the site. However, recommendations of a particular software with a certain set of specifications would be off-topic on the site.

This is completely my opinion. The [help center](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) is not clear regarding these type of questions, so maybe Sean would be the right person to decide on the scope of such questions.

Answer (score -1):

"On topic" is necessarily somewhat subjective, and the "off topic" reason is often used to mean "maybe on topic here, but more on topic in another Stack Exchange". This is borderline for this StackExchange since it sounds like you're just looking for a BI tool recommendation. This SE tends to be more about engineering statistical / machine learning solutions in a language or environment. I think it's legitimate to suggest it's better at Software Recommendations; IIRC for some reason it would not let me migrate it.

Comment: Off-topic shouldn't be used to mean "maybe on topic here, but more on topic in another Stack Exchange".  If you see that happening, it'd be great to encourage people not to do that.  If after seeing the question people feel that it shouldn't be on-topic here, it would be better to discuss the scope of the site and establish some guidelines about our scope.